# PHP json decode for java returned escaped json

Tags: php, json

I have the following json returning from java classes. I can get this to work with JS. However, when using json decode in php it obviously breaks as I am sure I need to use regexp to get it to parse properly. Any ideas?

```
{"return":"{\"response\": {\n \"header\": {\"status\": \"SUCCESS\"},\n \"table\":   {\"rows\": {\"row\": {\"category\": [ {\n \"id\": 1,\n \"name\": \"myApp\",\n \"fa\": [\n {\n \"id\": \"370\",\n \"FieldsAllowed\": \"true\",\n \"systemType\": \"CRM GT\",\n \"cachable\": \"false\",\n \"description\": \"Display Activities\",\n \"faId\": \"100000044\",\n  }]}}}\n}}"}
```

Comment: No, you probably don't need regex. There's simply an encoded string within, not a subarray. Someone made the original mistake at encoding.

Comment: unfortunately this is what I'm stuck with, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the data either as an associative array or an object,

```
$jsonString = '{"return":"{\"response\": {\n \"header\": {\"status\": \"SUCCESS\"},\n \"table\":   {\"rows\": {\"row\": {\"category\": [ {\n \"id\": 1,\n \"name\": \"myApp\",\n \"fa\": [\n {\n \"id\": \"370\",\n \"FieldsAllowed\": \"true\",\n \"systemType\": \"CRM GT\",\n \"cachable\": \"false\",\n \"description\": \"Display Activities\",\n \"faId\": \"100000044\",\n  }]}}}\n}}"}';
```

1) Get the response as an associative array,

```
$decodedResultsAsArray = json_decode($jsonString,true);
$data = $decodedResultsAsArray['return'];
print_r($data);
```

2) Get the response as an object,

```
$decodedResultsAsObject = json_decode($jsonString);
$data = $decodedResultsAsObject->return;
print_r($data);
```

There are several other options with the json_decode function if you want to look at, http://php.net/json_decode

Answer (score 0):

Apply [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode) twice to get the contained array ("response").

```
 // This gets you the inner string
 $json = json_decode($input);

 // This unfolds the contained structure
 $data = json_decode($data->return);
```

Just as you would do in all cases when data was marshalled twice.

Comment: ok, I tried the following several ways and no go? im still relearning php so i guess I dont understand how the $data var was created? 

    //execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    //close connection
    curl_close($ch);
 
    //Print($AgentString);
    $json = json_decode($result);

     // This unfolds the contained structure
    $data = json_decode($json->return);

    Print($data);

Comment: ok, im getting Null which means its not liking the json somehow. good news is im getting a result at least.